# egrep command to find substrings whose length is multiple of 3

Tags: linux, shell, command

I wonder if you can tell me what's the command to find substrings in a txt file that contain these characters A, C, G, T and have a length of a multiple of 3

My command is this

```
egrep "[ACGT]" dna.txt
```

but I'm still stuck with the multiple of 3 part. I guess I will have to use `{}` but I don't know how.

Comment: What should be output if a line contains, say, the string _TACA_ (which has length 4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rephrase your requirement, you want one or more repetitions of a sequence of three matches.

```
grep -E -x '([ACGT]{3})+' dna.txt
```

In some more detail, the parentheses are for grouping, so that the final `+` (one or more) applies to the whole group; and inside the group, the simple expression `[ACGT]{3}` matches three adjacent characters where each one can be any one from the enumeration in the character class.

`grep` by default prints out any line which contains *a substring* which matches; the `-x` requires the whole line to match.

The `egrep` synonym for `grep -E` is obsolescent and should probably be avoided going forward.

Comment: I see. Thank you! I wonder what's the difference between the two? My class is using egrep. My prof said they're interchangable

Comment: Yeah, as already spelled out, they are synonyms, but `egrep` is a legacy term which will continue to work but should not be taught to beginners. Maybe tip off your prof to review the POSIX spec. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-egrep-and-fgrep

Answer (score 0):

Note that plain old `grep` can do this, albeit more verbosely:

```
grep -o '[ACGT][ACGT][ACGT]' <<< TACA
```

Output:

```
TAC
```

Comment: Just for fun, behold the DNA of the `bash` manual:  `man bash | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | grep -o '[ACGT][ACGT][ACGT]' | xargs echo`

Comment: Of course, that *extracts* any group of three, not a line which contains a multiple of three. POSIX `grep` BRE syntax supports `\([ACGT]\{3\}\)\+` which is wacky and inelegant, but reasonably portable to the current millennium.

Comment: The square brackets in the argument to `tr` are not wrong (because you translate `[` to `[` and `]` to `]`), but completely superfluous

Comment: @tripleee, True, but the OP specificied *substrings* as input as part of some undefined file structure.  Anyway, for *whole* lines, there's `grep  '^[ACGT][ACGT][ACGT]$' `.

Comment: Or equivalently `grep -x` as in my answer.

Comment: @tripleee, Thanks.  Revised `bash` DNA:  `man bash | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' | grep -o '[ACGT][ACGT][ACGT]' | xargs echo`